# Solve the equation [a]m[x]m=[b]m by finding convenient representatives for [a] and [b]

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need to solve this for $[6]_{10}[x]_{10}=[4]_{10}$. So if I am understanding the question correctly I need to solve for the values of $x$. So to do this I know that $[x]_{10}=([6]_{10})^{-1}*[4]_{10}$. Since there is no value for the inverse of $6$ modulo $10$, I presume that there is no solution for $x$. However, I am unsure of whether I understood the question correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I am able to solve the problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that $[6]10$ is same as $6 \mod 10$.

You want to solve
$$
6 x \equiv 4 \mod 10 \Rightarrow 6 x \equiv 4 \mod 2, ~\text{and }~  6 x \equiv 4 \mod 5
$$
First of the two condition is vacuously true so you are left with $x \equiv 4 \mod 5$ giving
$$
x \equiv 4, x \equiv 9 \mod 10
$$
Thus there are two solutions

Answer (score 0):

It suggests how to do it: find convenient representatives. Do you know a number that's $6\mod10$ that, when muliplied by another number, yields a number that's $4\mod10$? (Hint: you do. $6$ is one. Now figure out what the other multiplicand can be.)